# How to call an array of arrays on php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, arrays

I would like to access to the data inside an array of array that I'm sending with ajax to a .php page.

Creating the array of arrays in the function before sending

```
var xi = new Array(maxests);
$(".mtable").find(".allownumericwithdecimal").each(function(){
var nth = ((i) % maxests) + 3
var alt = $(this).parent().parent().find("td:first").html()
var est = $('.mtable').find("thead tr:first td:nth-child("+nth+")").html()
var pay = $(this).val()

xi[i] = new Array(alt,est,pay);
    i++;
})
```

Output on php:

```
Array(
[data] => Array
    (
      [name] => 
      [description] => 
      [project] => 1
      [ae] => [["Alternativa 1","Estado N. 1","1"],["Alternativa 1","Estado N. 2","23"],["Alternativa 2","Estado N. 1","33"],["Alternativa 2","Estado N. 2","43"]]
    ))
```

I would like to access the data inside ae.

> echo $_POST['data']['ae'][0][0];

I'm trying this one, but not luck. How can I get the value of each one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If that's a `var_dump($_POST)` or `print_r($_POST)`, then this

```
[ae] => [["Alternativa 1","Estado N. 1","1"],["Alternativa 1","Estado N. 2","23"],["Alternativa 2","Estado N. 1","33"],["Alternativa 2","Estado N. 2","43"]]
```

is a string

```
$ae=json_decode($_POST['data']['ae']);

echo $ae[0][0]; // what you thought $_POST['data']['ae'][0][0]; would do

foreach ($ae as $a){
    print_r($a);
}
```

https://www.php.net/json_decode

Comment: @Maky-chan sorry - typo

Answer (score 0):

Your array appears to be in an array

```
  $ae = $_POST[0]['data']['ae'];
  print_r($ae);
```

Should give you the breakdown of $ae. So in your example the first element of the first array would be

```
  echo $_POST[0]['data']['ae'][0][0];
```

output:

```
  Alternativa 1
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Your "solution" is exactly what was reported in the question as not working. OP thought that it was an array.